# Some Javascript + CSS + Images returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

I already search all the web but can't find any problem similar.

**Note: The following problem only occurs on production.**

In my mvc website if i reload any page multiple times, css, javascript files and images begin to give "500 - Internal Server Error".

**It doesn't happen with all the files**. Some of the files that are giving the error are: fontawesome.min.css and chartnew.js.

If i call the **files directly they work**, but **if i reload** they begin to give the **asp default error page** "500 - Internal Server Error" without any other details (Already tried without custom errors and using detailed error view).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved removing this at the webconfig:

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompressions="True" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I removed WebDav by clicking, **Handler Mapping**->**WebDav module***->**Request Restrictions**->**Verbs**-> **All verbs**.

This will add an entry to your web.config. But then later I decided to remove WebDav from IIS (Remove Features). However, in the web.config, WebDav was still referenced.

Removed all references to WebDav in Web.config, and it worked.

**Conclusion:** When removing WebDav from IIS, make sure there is no reference to it in web.config.