# HTTP500: SERVER ERROR on aspx page only appears on edge

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I've been trying to setup so that the website supports multiple browsers
The page was initially debugged on chrome with no issues. the same can be said to IE, Firefox, Opera

When debugged on Edge though the page shows up with no CSS and the javascripts implemented doesn't work

Edge Version

- Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
- Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

Declared on aspx

```html
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
```

I'm have narrowed down the issue to what I think is the cause, the browser can't seem to locate all the scripts that has been added to it. 
These errors don't appear on the other browsers

> HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. GET - https://localhost:44311/assets/css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css

Comment: Its something to do with your server. Its preventing the browser from accessing your css file

Comment: The best way to find the detailed error is to log all your server errors in a file and see the actual cause of the error

Comment: It could be caused by your `src`, try moving your `css`/`js` to another location a refrence it from there.

Comment: @MuhammadHannanAwan I'm not familiar with the log file, can you specify what should I be looking for?

Comment: @HaldenCollier still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the browser cache, then retest your code.

Also, you could try to add a new folder and put the JS and CSS file into it, then using them.

If still not working, you could also try to use the CDN reference to add the JQuery UI JavaScript or CSS reference. like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

More details, see [jQuery UI – All Versions](https://code.jquery.com/ui/) and [jQuery UI 1.9.2](https://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/11/jquery-ui-1-9-2/).

Comment: Still got the same error.
I can use CDN reference fine but I still need to use local references.
The issue is not limited to js files even css and images references are getting the error.

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with your server side, please refer to the following threads to enable the detailed error messages from server side and check the detailed error message. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954037/some-javascript-css-images-returns-500-internal-server-error) and [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5).